# Graphing date vs time on plotly

Tags: python, plot, plotly

I have several data sets I would like to plot with dates as X axis and times as Y axis. I am working in Jupyter Notebook.

```
from datetime import date, time
from plotly import offline as py
from plotly.graph_objs import Scatter, Data
py.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

meetings = Scatter(
    x=[date(2017, 1, 1), date(2017, 1, 3), date(2017, 1, 3)],
    y=[time(8, 0, 0), time(12, 0, 0), time(16, 0, 0)],
    text=['work meeting 1', 'work meeting 1', 'work meeting 1'],
    mode='markers'
)

workouts = Scatter(
    x=[date(2017, 1, 1), date(2017, 1, 2), date(2017, 1, 2)],
    y=[time(7, 30, 0), time(14, 30, 0), time(17, 0, 0)],
    text=['workout 1', 'workout 2', 'workout 3'],
    mode='markers'
)

data = Data([meetings, workouts])
py.iplot(data)
```

The result I get is this:
[image: result]
The X axis includes time as well, and the Y axis goes in order of inserted data, not from bottom to top. Nothing I've tried with modifying the range/domain has fixed this.
From what I've seen on the  [help page](http://help.plot.ly/date-format-and-time-series/) time objects aren't supported.
Is there any way to make this type of plot work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to plot hours you would need to do two things:

- Set the yaxis `type` to date and the `tickformat` to `%H:%M`
- Convert your `time` objects to `datetime` objects

We just pretend everything on the yaxis happened on the same day but we only report the hour.

[image]

```
import plotly
import datetime as dt

meetings = plotly.graph_objs.Scatter(
    x=[dt.date(2017, 1, 1), dt.date(2017, 1, 3), dt.date(2017, 1, 3)],
    y=[dt.time(8, 0, 0), dt.time(12, 0, 0), dt.time(16, 0, 0)],
    text=['work meeting 1', 'work meeting 1', 'work meeting 1'],
    mode='markers'
)

workouts = plotly.graph_objs.Scatter(
    x=[dt.date(2017, 1, 1), dt.date(2017, 1, 2), dt.date(2017, 1, 2)],
    y=[dt.time(7, 30, 0), dt.time(14, 30, 0), dt.time(17, 0, 0)],
    text=['workout 1', 'workout 2', 'workout 3'],
    mode='markers'
)

for d in [meetings, workouts]:
    for i, t in enumerate(d.y):
        d.y[i] = dt.datetime.combine(dt.date(2017, 1, 1), t)

layout = plotly.graph_objs.Layout(yaxis={
    'type': 'date',
    'tickformat': '%H:%M'
    }
)

fig = plotly.graph_objs.Figure(
    data=plotly.graph_objs.Data([meetings, workouts]),
    layout=layout
)
plotly.offline.plot(fig)
```