# Displaying Plotly histogram time in hh:mm:ss

Tags: r, plotly

I have a vector of marathon finishing times I want to plot as a histogram with the x-axis/bins in hours and minutes `hh:mm:ss` format using the `plot_ly` function in R.

```
library(plotly)

R<-c("02:17:20", "02:17:26", "02:19:17", "02:19:18", "02:20:50", "02:21:20")

plot_ly(x = as.difftime(R), type = "histogram")
```

The x-axis and the popup on the chart displays in decimal format i.e `2.325` instead of `2:19:30` I assume this is because I'm using the `difftime`class. Is it possible to change the formatting of the graph to show it in `hh:mm:ss` format?

[Plot_ly running times histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9pef.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the same trick like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42027819/graphing-date-vs-time-on-plotly/42030690#42030690), i.e. convert your hours into datetime. Let's pretend they all finished on 1970/01/01 at some time, but we will only report the hours (`tickformat="%H:%M:%S"`).

Please note that this will look a bit different than your original example, because plotly arbitrarily decides to place the bins differently.

```
library(plotly)
library('magrittr')

R<-c("02:17:20", "02:17:26", "02:17:46", "02:18:26", "02:18:46", "02:19:17", "02:19:18", "02:20:50", "02:21:20")

R <- paste('1970-01-01', R)
R <- strptime(R, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

plot_ly(x = (as.numeric(R) * 1000), type = "histogram") %>% 
  layout(xaxis=list(type="date", tickformat="%H:%M:%S"))
```

[image]

Comment: That works great thanks. Just for my understanding in the `plot_ly` call you are multiplying the numeric datetime by 1000 because in plotly/js datetimes are counted as milliseconds from 1970/01/01 and in R its seconds?